# Django Rest Framework - Nested List Inside JSON Response

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm very new to both Django and the Django Rest Framework, and I'm struggling with building up a particular JSON response. I have two models, like so:

```
class Artist(models.model):
  artist_id = models.CharField(
    max_length=256,
    primary_key=True,
  )
  name = models.CharField(
    max_length=256,
    null=False,
    blank=False,
  )
  birthplace =  models.CharField(
    max_length=256,
    null=False,
    blank=False,
  )

class Album(models.Model):
  artist = models.ForeignKey(
    Artist,
    on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,
    db_constraint=False,
    null=True,
  )
  name = models.CharField(
    max_length=256,
    null=False,
    blank=False,
  )
  label = models.CharField(
    max_length=256,
    null=False,
    blank=False,
  )
```

I'm trying to build a JSON response that looks like this, where the albums are nested inside the artist:

```
{
    "artist_id": "A123",
    "name": "Bob Dylan",
    "birtplace": "Duluth, Minnesota",
    "albums": [
        {
            "id": 123,
            "name": "Bob Dylan",
            "label": "Columbia"
        },
        {
            "id": 123,
            "name": "The Freewheelin' Bob Dylan",
            "label": "Columbia"
        }
    ]
}
```

Is this even possible? I was looking into select_related, but that doesn't seem to work as I feel like I need to 'hit' the Artist table first, and there is no relationship defined in the direction of Artist to Album.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to make a serializer that matches the JSON response that provides in your question, this will be something like that:

```
class AlbumSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    name = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)
    label = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)

class ArtistSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    artist_id = serializers.CharField(read_only=True) # I suggest to use the defult id field that comes with Django for now.
    name = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)
    birthplace = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)
```

This is a simple serializer, right?
Let's build your views and assume this is a `GET` request and I prefer using `APIView`

```
class ListApi(APIView):

    def get(self, request):

        artist = Artist.objects.all()

        artist_serializer = ArtistSerializer(albums, many=True).data
    
        '''
        artist_serializer will give us this data, right?

        {
            "artist_id": "A123",
            "name": "Bob Dylan",
            "birtplace": "Duluth, Minnesota",
        }

        So, for every artist in this data have multiple Album, so we need to fetch all albums that belong to this artist.
        '''

        for artist in artist_serializer:
            albums = Album.objects.filter(artist=artist['id'])
            artist['albums'] = AlbumSerializer(albums, many=True).data

        return Response(artist_serializer)
```

If you face any issues with understanding the code, feel free to ask!